# What SQL Functions are Available in NetSuite saved searches?

Tags: sql-server, netsuite

What SQL functions are available in NetSuite saved searches (formulas)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The following is a list of SQL functions (shown as example code) available to use in NetSuite saved searches as of September 2019.  These saved searches do not allow all SQL functions so it is helpful to know what is available to work with.

If you have a NetSuite account with access to SuiteAnswers you can follow this link to [Answer Id: 10101](https://netsuite.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/10101/kw/10101).

It took me a while to find this since it didn't show up in web searches.  I want to make it easy to find.  Enjoy!

## Numeric Functions

```
ABS( {amount} )
ACOS( 0.35 )
ASIN( 1 )
ATAN( 0.2 )
ATAN2( 0.2, 0.3 )
BITAND( 5, 3 )
CEIL( {today}-{createddate} )
COS( 0.35 )
COSH( -3.15 )
EXP( {rate} )
FLOOR( {today}-{createddate} )
LN( 20 )
LOG( 10, 20 )
MOD( 3:56 pm-{lastmessagedate},7 )
NANVL( {itemisbn13}, '' )
POWER( {custcoldaystoship},-.196 )
REMAINDER( {transaction.totalamount}, {transaction.amountpaid} )
ROUND( ( {today}-{startdate} ), 0 )
SIGN( {quantity} )
SIN( 5.2 )
SINH( 3 )
SQRT( POWER( {taxamount}, 2 ) )
TAN( -5.2 )
TANH( 3 )
TRUNC( {amount}, 1 )
```

## Character Functions Returning Character Values

```
CHR( 13 )
CONCAT( {number}​,​CONCAT( ​'​_​'​,​{​line}​ )​ )
INITCAP( {customer.​companyname}​ )
LOWER( {customer.​companyname}​ )
LPAD( {line},3,'0' )
LTRIM( {companyname},'-' )
REGEXP_REPLACE( {name}, '^.*:', '' )
REGEXP_SUBSTR( ​{​item}​,​'​[​^​:​]​+​$​'​ )
REPLACE( {serialnumber}, '&', ',' )
RPAD( {firstname},20 )
RTRIM( {paidtransaction.​externalid}​,​'​-​Invoice'​ )
SOUNDEX( {companyname} )
SUBSTR( {transaction.​salesrep}​,​1,​3 )
TRANSLATE( ​{​expensecategory}​,​ ' ', '+' )
TRIM ( BOTH ',' FROM {custrecord_assetcost} )
UPPER( {unit} )
```

## Character Functions Returning Number Values

```
ASCII( {taxitem} )
INSTR( {messages.message}, 'cspdr3' )
LENGTH( {name} )
REGEXP_INSTR ( {item.unitstype}, '\d' )
TO_NUMBER( {quantity} )
```

## Datetime Functions

```
ADD_MONTHS( {today},-1 )
LAST_DAY( {today} )
MONTHS_BETWEEN( ​SYSDATE,​{​createddate}​ )

NEXT_DAY( {today},'SATURDAY' )
ROUND( TO_DATE( '12/31/2014', 'mm/dd/yyyy' )-{datecreated} )
TO_CHAR( {date}, 'hh24' )
TO_DATE( '31.12.2011', 'DD.MM.YYYY' )
TRUNC( {today},'YYYY' )
```

Also see Sysdate in one of the example sections below.

## NULL-Related Functions

```
COALESCE( {quantitycommitted}, 0 )
NULLIF( {price}, 0 )
NVL( {quantity},'0' )
NVL2( {location}, 1, 2 )
```

## Decode

```
DECODE( {systemnotes.name}, {assigned},'T','F' )
```

## Sysdate

```
TO_DATE( SYSDATE, 'DD.MM.YYYY' )
```

*or*

```
TO_CHAR( SYSDATE, 'mm/dd/yyyy' )
```

See also TO_DATE and TO_CHAR in the Datetime Functions.

## Case

```
CASE {state}
WHEN 'NY' THEN 'New York'
WHEN 'CA' THEN 'California'
ELSE {state}
END
```

*or*

```
CASE
WHEN {quantityavailable} > 19 THEN 'In Stock'
WHEN {quantityavailable} > 1 THEN 'Limited Availability'
WHEN {quantityavailable} = 1 THEN 'The Last Piece'
WHEN {quantityavailable} IS NULL THEN 'Discontinued'
ELSE 'Out of Stock'
END
```

## Analytic and Aggregate Functions

```
DENSE_RANK ( {amount} WITHIN GROUP ( ORDER BY {AMOUNT} ) )
```

*or*

```
DENSE_RANK(  ) OVER ( PARTITION BY {name}ORDER BY {trandate} DESC )
KEEP( DENSE_RANK LAST ORDER BY {internalid} )
RANK(  ) OVER ( PARTITION by {tranid} ORDER BY {line} DESC )
```

*or*

```
RANK ( {amount} WITHIN GROUP ( ORDER BY {amount} ) )
```

Comment: Why didn't you just call the link `Answer Id: 21`? :)

Comment: @tagyoureit, there are 10 types of people in this world - those who understand binary and those who don't.

Comment: @tagyoureit Yes this is pulled straight from SuiteAnswers.