# Customer SQL USING SELECT COUNT(*) in TABLEAU RETURNING ZERO

Tags: tableau-api

I'm using TABLEAU Datasource option to run Custom SQL "Select count(*) from table_name. It is based on a ODBC connection. Unfortunately, I have 400 tables that I need to run my script with 400 lines of "Select count(*)" , Tableau is not returning the total # of records and is only returning ZEROs. I'm using the Edit Custom SQL option from the Datasource Tab.

I have tried using the View Result after Opening the Edit Customer SQL and selecting the View Result to get the total count. My plan was to include all he 400 select counts in one script and run it. It worked fine as a part of my connection to another database but not ODBC.

SELECT COUNT(*) FROM  ACCOUNTING_BOOKS

The expected result should be,
Select Edit Customer SQL
View Result
Get a listing of counts.

Comment: NetSuite is the main database that I'm trying to get counts of the tables. Here is the error I'm getting, An error occurred while communicating with the Other Databases (ODBC) data source 'ShowData'.


An error occurred while loading the data.
[NetSuite][ODBC 64bit driver][OpenAccess SDK SQL Engine]Syntax Error in the SQL statement.[10104]

Answer (score 0):

According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39131715/what-sql-functions-are-available-in-netsuite-saved-searches) answer `count` isn't available as a NetSuite function.  You might want to follow the link in that article (if you have a NetSuite account) to see if this has changed.